# Как мне сделать чтобы игрок водил ник и значение которые он вёл перевело к другому файлу которые связан Python, но тот файл на java или cmd скрипте

Tags: python, java, minecraft

У меня есть 2 файла - 1 основной это лаунчер файл Python
и 2 файл - запускатор (батник) которые сделан на java вроде, но они все работают на консоли (cmd windows)

Так вот, так мне сделать чтобы например человек ввёл Klispor то и на другой батник тоже ввёлся? Там есть пункт "name" которые обозначен "%name%", я что то попробовал но когда я заходил на сервер - мой ник: MissingName а не klispor.

Код основного лаунчера:

```py
from colorama import init, Fore #/
from colorama import Back       #|
from colorama import Style      #|
import msvcrt                   #|
import subprocess
import sys
import os
import time
import getpass
#-----------Библы-----------------

os.system("title 〡ELauncher • Ядро: SCore")

print("")
print(Fore.WHITE + "      ███████╗██╗░░░░░░█████╗░██╗░░░██╗███╗░░██╗░█████╗░██╗░░██╗███████╗██████╗░")
print(Fore.WHITE + "      ██╔════╝██║░░░░░██╔══██╗██║░░░██║████╗░██║██╔══██╗██║░░██║██╔════╝██╔══██╗")
print(Fore.BLUE + "      █████╗░░██║░░░░░███████║██║░░░██║██╔██╗██║██║░░╚═╝███████║█████╗░░██████╔╝")
print(Fore.BLUE + "      ██╔══╝░░██║░░░░░██╔══██║██║░░░██║██║╚████║██║░░██╗██╔══██║██╔══╝░░██╔══██╗")
print(Fore.RED + "      ███████╗███████╗██║░░██║╚██████╔╝██║░╚███║╚█████╔╝██║░░██║███████╗██║░░██║")
print(Fore.RED + "      ╚══════╝╚══════╝╚═╝░░╚═╝░╚═════╝░╚═╝░░╚══╝░╚════╝░╚═╝░░╚═╝╚══════╝╚═╝░░╚═╝")
print(Style.RESET_ALL)
print("                От создателей EscapeWorld〡Выбран сервер: SCreate")
print(" ")
print("Выберите:")
print("1: Старт игры")
print("2: Выбор версии")
print("3: Настройка лаунчера")
print("4: Изменение игрового-никнейма")

def get_char():
    return msvcrt.getch().decode('utf-8')

option = ""

current_directory = 'C:/ELauncher'
my_path = os.path.join(current_directory, 'start.bat')

while True:
    key = get_char()
    if key == "1":
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        print("")
        print(Fore.WHITE + "      ███████╗██╗░░░░░░█████╗░██╗░░░██╗███╗░░██╗░█████╗░██╗░░██╗███████╗██████╗░")
        print(Fore.WHITE + "      ██╔════╝██║░░░░░██╔══██╗██║░░░██║████╗░██║██╔══██╗██║░░██║██╔════╝██╔══██╗")
        print(Fore.BLUE + "      █████╗░░██║░░░░░███████║██║░░░██║██╔██╗██║██║░░╚═╝███████║█████╗░░██████╔╝")
        print(Fore.BLUE + "      ██╔══╝░░██║░░░░░██╔══██║██║░░░██║██║╚████║██║░░██╗██╔══██║██╔══╝░░██╔══██╗")
        print(Fore.RED + "      ███████╗███████╗██║░░██║╚██████╔╝██║░╚███║╚█████╔╝██║░░██║███████╗██║░░██║")
        print(Fore.RED + "      ╚══════╝╚══════╝╚═╝░░╚═╝░╚═════╝░╚═╝░░╚══╝░╚════╝░╚═╝░░╚═╝╚══════╝╚═╝░░╚═╝")
        print(Style.RESET_ALL)
        print("                От создателей EscapeWorld〡Выбран сервер: SCreate")
        print("Введите ник:")
        name = input("> ")
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        print("")
        print(Fore.WHITE + "      ███████╗██╗░░░░░░█████╗░██╗░░░██╗███╗░░██╗░█████╗░██╗░░██╗███████╗██████╗░")
        print(Fore.WHITE + "      ██╔════╝██║░░░░░██╔══██╗██║░░░██║████╗░██║██╔══██╗██║░░██║██╔════╝██╔══██╗")
        print(Fore.BLUE + "      █████╗░░██║░░░░░███████║██║░░░██║██╔██╗██║██║░░╚═╝███████║█████╗░░██████╔╝")
        print(Fore.BLUE + "      ██╔══╝░░██║░░░░░██╔══██║██║░░░██║██║╚████║██║░░██╗██╔══██║██╔══╝░░██╔══██╗")
        print(Fore.RED + "      ███████╗███████╗██║░░██║╚██████╔╝██║░╚███║╚█████╔╝██║░░██║███████╗██║░░██║")
        print(Fore.RED + "      ╚══════╝╚══════╝╚═╝░░╚═╝░╚═════╝░╚═╝░░╚══╝░╚════╝░╚═╝░░╚═╝╚══════╝╚═╝░░╚═╝")
        print(Style.RESET_ALL)
        print("                От создателей EscapeWorld〡Выбран сервер: SCreate")
        print("Ник: ", name)
        time.sleep(2.5)
        #print("Проверяю...")
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        print("")
        print(Fore.WHITE + "      ███████╗██╗░░░░░░█████╗░██╗░░░██╗███╗░░██╗░█████╗░██╗░░██╗███████╗██████╗░")
        print(Fore.WHITE + "      ██╔════╝██║░░░░░██╔══██╗██║░░░██║████╗░██║██╔══██╗██║░░██║██╔════╝██╔══██╗")
        print(Fore.BLUE + "      █████╗░░██║░░░░░███████║██║░░░██║██╔██╗██║██║░░╚═╝███████║█████╗░░██████╔╝")
        print(Fore.BLUE + "      ██╔══╝░░██║░░░░░██╔══██║██║░░░██║██║╚████║██║░░██╗██╔══██║██╔══╝░░██╔══██╗")
        print(Fore.RED + "      ███████╗███████╗██║░░██║╚██████╔╝██║░╚███║╚█████╔╝██║░░██║███████╗██║░░██║")
        print(Fore.RED + "      ╚══════╝╚══════╝╚═╝░░╚═╝░╚═════╝░╚═╝░░╚══╝░╚════╝░╚═╝░░╚═╝╚══════╝╚═╝░░╚═╝")
        print(Style.RESET_ALL)
        print("                От создателей EscapeWorld〡Выбран сервер: SCreate")
        print("Проверяем обновление...")
        time.sleep(2.5)
        print("Проверяем файлы...")
        time.sleep(2.5)
        subprocess.run([my_path], check=False) # -jar OptiFine 1.18.2.jar shell=True,
        time.sleep(2.5)
        break
        #time.sleep(2.5)
    elif key == "2":
        option = "Выбор версии"
        print("Пункт «Выбор версии» в разработке :[")
    elif key == "3":
        option = "Настройка лаунчера"
        print("Пункт «Настройка лаунчера» в разработке :[")
    elif key == "q":
        break
        print(option)
```

Код запускатора (Батника)

```
echo off
cls
title МОЖЕТЕ ЗАКРЫТЬ ДАННОЕ ОКНО ЕСЛИ ОНО ВАМ МЕШАЕТ! РАЗРАБОТЧИК КРИВОРУКИЙ НЕ УМЕЕТ ДЕЛАТЬ ЛАУНЧЕРА ДЛЯ MINECRAFT 1.18.2!
echo                                      МОЖЕТЕ ЗАКРЫТЬ ДАННОЕ ОКНО!!!
echo ░██████╗████████╗░█████╗░██████╗░████████╗  ███╗░░░███╗██╗███╗░░██╗███████╗░█████╗░██████╗░░█████╗░███████╗████████╗
echo ██╔════╝╚══██╔══╝██╔══██╗██╔══██╗╚══██╔══╝  ████╗░████║██║████╗░██║██╔════╝██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██╔════╝╚══██╔══╝
echo ╚█████╗░░░░██║░░░███████║██████╔╝░░░██║░░░  ██╔████╔██║██║██╔██╗██║█████╗░░██║░░╚═╝██████╔╝███████║█████╗░░░░░██║░░░
echo ░╚═══██╗░░░██║░░░██╔══██║██╔══██╗░░░██║░░░  ██║╚██╔╝██║██║██║╚████║██╔══╝░░██║░░██╗██╔══██╗██╔══██║██╔══╝░░░░░██║░░░
echo ██████╔╝░░░██║░░░██║░░██║██║░░██║░░░██║░░░  ██║░╚═╝░██║██║██║░╚███║███████╗╚█████╔╝██║░░██║██║░░██║██║░░░░░░░░██║░░░
echo ╚═════╝░░░░╚═╝░░░╚═╝░░╚═╝╚═╝░░╚═╝░░░╚═╝░░░  ╚═╝░░░░░╚═╝╚═╝╚═╝░░╚══╝╚══════╝░╚════╝░╚═╝░░╚═╝╚═╝░░╚═╝╚═╝░░░░░░░░╚═╝░░░
C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\jre\java-runtime-beta\windows-x64\java-runtime-beta\bin\javaw.exe -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -Xms512M -Xmx2816M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump "-Djava.library.path=C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\versions\ForgeOptiFine 1.18.2\natives" -Dminecraft.launcher.brand=java-minecraft-launcher -Dminecraft.launcher.version=1.6.84-j -cp "C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\pw\modder\transformerDiscoverer\2.2\transformerDiscoverer-2.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\cpw\mods\securejarhandler\1.0.8\securejarhandler-1.0.8.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\ow2\asm\asm\9.5\asm-9.5.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\ow2\asm\asm-commons\9.5\asm-commons-9.5.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\ow2\asm\asm-tree\9.5\asm-tree-9.5.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\ow2\asm\asm-util\9.5\asm-util-9.5.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\ow2\asm\asm-analysis\9.5\asm-analysis-9.5.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\net\minecraftforge\accesstransformers\8.0.4\accesstransformers-8.0.4.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\antlr\antlr4-runtime\4.9.1\antlr4-runtime-4.9.1.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\net\minecraftforge\eventbus\5.0.3\eventbus-5.0.3.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\net\minecraftforge\forgespi\4.0.15-4.x\forgespi-4.0.15-4.x.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\net\minecraftforge\coremods\5.0.1\coremods-5.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\cpw\mods\modlauncher\9.1.3\modlauncher-9.1.3.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\net\minecraftforge\unsafe\0.2.0\unsafe-0.2.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\com\electronwill\night-config\core\3.6.4\core-3.6.4.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\com\electronwill\night-config\toml\3.6.4\toml-3.6.4.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\apache\maven\maven-artifact\3.6.3\maven-artifact-3.6.3.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\net\jodah\typetools\0.8.3\typetools-0.8.3.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\net\minecrell\terminalconsoleappender\1.2.0\terminalconsoleappender-1.2.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\jline\jline-reader\3.12.1\jline-reader-3.12.1.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\jline\jline-terminal\3.12.1\jline-terminal-3.12.1.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\spongepowered\mixin\0.8.5\mixin-0.8.5.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\openjdk\nashorn\nashorn-core\15.3\nashorn-core-15.3.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\net\minecraftforge\JarJarSelector\0.3.19\JarJarSelector-0.3.19.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\net\minecraftforge\JarJarMetadata\0.3.19\JarJarMetadata-0.3.19.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\cpw\mods\bootstraplauncher\1.0.0\bootstraplauncher-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\net\minecraftforge\JarJarFileSystems\0.3.19\JarJarFileSystems-0.3.19.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\net\minecraftforge\fmlloader\1.18.2-40.2.17\fmlloader-1.18.2-40.2.17.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\com\mojang\logging\1.0.0\logging-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\com\mojang\blocklist\1.0.10\blocklist-1.0.10.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\ru\tln4\empty\0.1\empty-0.1.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\com\github\oshi\oshi-core\5.8.5\oshi-core-5.8.5.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\net\java\dev\jna\jna\5.10.0\jna-5.10.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\net\java\dev\jna\jna-platform\5.10.0\jna-platform-5.10.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.8.0-beta4\slf4j-api-1.8.0-beta4.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-slf4j18-impl\2.17.0\log4j-slf4j18-impl-2.17.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\com\ibm\icu\icu4j\70.1\icu4j-70.1.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\com\mojang\javabridge\1.2.24\javabridge-1.2.24.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\net\sf\jopt-simple\jopt-simple\5.0.4\jopt-simple-5.0.4.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\io\netty\netty-all\4.1.68.Final\netty-all-4.1.68.Final.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\com\google\guava\failureaccess\1.0.1\failureaccess-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\com\google\guava\guava\31.0.1-jre\guava-31.0.1-jre.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.12.0\commons-lang3-3.12.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\commons-io\commons-io\2.11.0\commons-io-2.11.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.15\commons-codec-1.15.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\com\mojang\brigadier\1.0.18\brigadier-1.0.18.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\com\mojang\datafixerupper\4.1.27\datafixerupper-4.1.27.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.8.9\gson-2.8.9.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\by\ely\authlib\3.11.49.2\authlib-3.11.49.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.21\commons-compress-1.21.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.5.13\httpclient-4.5.13.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.2\commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.4.14\httpcore-4.4.14.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\it\unimi\dsi\fastutil\8.5.6\fastutil-8.5.6.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.17.0\log4j-api-2.17.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.17.0\log4j-core-2.17.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\3.2.2\lwjgl-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-jemalloc\3.2.2\lwjgl-jemalloc-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-openal\3.2.2\lwjgl-openal-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-opengl\3.2.2\lwjgl-opengl-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-glfw\3.2.2\lwjgl-glfw-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-stb\3.2.2\lwjgl-stb-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-tinyfd\3.2.2\lwjgl-tinyfd-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\com\mojang\text2speech\1.12.4\text2speech-1.12.4.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\versions\ForgeOptiFine 1.18.2\ForgeOptiFine 1.18.2.jar" -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=system "-DignoreList=bootstraplauncher,securejarhandler,asm-commons,asm-util,asm-analysis,asm-tree,asm,JarJarFileSystems,client-extra,fmlcore,javafmllanguage,lowcodelanguage,mclanguage,forge-,ForgeOptiFine 1.18.2.jar" -DmergeModules=jna-5.10.0.jar,jna-platform-5.10.0.jar,java-objc-bridge-1.0.0.jar -DlibraryDirectory=C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries -p C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries/cpw/mods/bootstraplauncher/1.0.0/bootstraplauncher-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries/cpw/mods/securejarhandler/1.0.8/securejarhandler-1.0.8.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/9.5/asm-commons-9.5.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries/org/ow2/asm/asm-util/9.5/asm-util-9.5.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/9.5/asm-analysis-9.5.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/9.5/asm-tree-9.5.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries/org/ow2/asm/asm/9.5/asm-9.5.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries/net/minecraftforge/JarJarFileSystems/0.3.19/JarJarFileSystems-0.3.19.jar --add-modules ALL-MODULE-PATH --add-opens java.base/java.util.jar=cpw.mods.securejarhandler --add-opens java.base/java.lang.invoke=cpw.mods.securejarhandler --add-exports java.base/sun.security.util=cpw.mods.securejarhandler --add-exports jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns=java.naming -Dtransformers.list=optifine:OptiFine:1.18.2_HD_U_H9 -Xss2M cpw.mods.bootstraplauncher.BootstrapLauncher --username "%name%" --version "ForgeOptiFine 1.18.2" --gameDir C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game --assetsDir C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\assets --assetIndex 1.18 --uuid e8717b21d14941f4b2ce6455e5a14a5b --accessToken eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE3MDc0ODUzOTksImNsaWVudF9pZCI6InRsYXVuY2hlciIsInNjb3BlIjoib2J0YWluX293bl9hY2NvdW50X2luZm8gbWluZWNyYWZ0X3NlcnZlcl9zZXNzaW9uIiwic3ViIjoiZWx5fDQ5NDU3OTcifQ.SybKJkqa7Bv2VV9Wv7tUdeJgGE3GTcBD1tle9wo766xxVzAUh7c9Cs2un6k7i1baGUXL1m1XAfgnmrZCkcPIsA --clientId "" --xuid "" --userType mojang --versionType modified --width 925 --height 530 --launchTarget forgeclient --fml.forgeVersion 40.2.17 --fml.mcVersion 1.18.2 --fml.forgeGroup net.minecraftforge --fml.mcpVersion 20220404.173914 --server 65.21.9.198 --port 25988
```

Comment: Вместо запуска батника, сразу запускайте `.exe` через subprocess с нужными параметрами, куда и подставите никнейм.

Comment: Я делаю лаунчер для сервера, мне надо чтобы при воде никнейма json файл запомнил какой это никнейм и водил его постояно когда игрок заходит через лаунчер

Comment: Так все примеры уже дал: как записывать, как читать Json. Вам нужно только доработать под себя. И как уже говорил ранее: читаем запись из Json -> через subprocess запускаем javaw.exe и передаем свои параметры subprocess.run(["javaw.exe","Параметр1","Параметр2", name, " т.д."])

Comment: Если я запускаю через java [Длин.код] или javaw [Длин.код] то весь код просто не будет работать

Answer (score 0):

Основной:

```py
from colorama import init, Fore #/
from colorama import Back       #|
from colorama import Style      #|
import msvcrt                   #|
import subprocess
import sys
import os
import time
import getpass
import minecraft_launcher_lib
import json
#-----------Библы-----------------

os.system("title 〡ELauncher • Ядро: SCore")

print("")
print(Fore.WHITE + "      ███████╗██╗░░░░░░█████╗░██╗░░░██╗███╗░░██╗░█████╗░██╗░░██╗███████╗██████╗░")
print(Fore.WHITE + "      ██╔════╝██║░░░░░██╔══██╗██║░░░██║████╗░██║██╔══██╗██║░░██║██╔════╝██╔══██╗")
print(Fore.BLUE + "      █████╗░░██║░░░░░███████║██║░░░██║██╔██╗██║██║░░╚═╝███████║█████╗░░██████╔╝")
print(Fore.BLUE + "      ██╔══╝░░██║░░░░░██╔══██║██║░░░██║██║╚████║██║░░██╗██╔══██║██╔══╝░░██╔══██╗")
print(Fore.RED + "      ███████╗███████╗██║░░██║╚██████╔╝██║░╚███║╚█████╔╝██║░░██║███████╗██║░░██║")
print(Fore.RED + "      ╚══════╝╚══════╝╚═╝░░╚═╝░╚═════╝░╚═╝░░╚══╝░╚════╝░╚═╝░░╚═╝╚══════╝╚═╝░░╚═╝")
print(Style.RESET_ALL)
print("                От создателей EscapeWorld〡Выбран сервер: SCreate")
print(" ")
print("Выберите:")
print("1: Старт игры")
print("2: Выбор версии")
print("3: Настройка лаунчера")

def get_char():
    return msvcrt.getch().decode('utf-8')

option = ""

current_directory = 'C:/ELauncher'
my_path = os.path.join(current_directory, 'start.bat')

while True:
    key = get_char()
    if key == "1":
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        print("")
        print(Fore.WHITE + "      ███████╗██╗░░░░░░█████╗░██╗░░░██╗███╗░░██╗░█████╗░██╗░░██╗███████╗██████╗░")
        print(Fore.WHITE + "      ██╔════╝██║░░░░░██╔══██╗██║░░░██║████╗░██║██╔══██╗██║░░██║██╔════╝██╔══██╗")
        print(Fore.BLUE + "      █████╗░░██║░░░░░███████║██║░░░██║██╔██╗██║██║░░╚═╝███████║█████╗░░██████╔╝")
        print(Fore.BLUE + "      ██╔══╝░░██║░░░░░██╔══██║██║░░░██║██║╚████║██║░░██╗██╔══██║██╔══╝░░██╔══██╗")
        print(Fore.RED + "      ███████╗███████╗██║░░██║╚██████╔╝██║░╚███║╚█████╔╝██║░░██║███████╗██║░░██║")
        print(Fore.RED + "      ╚══════╝╚══════╝╚═╝░░╚═╝░╚═════╝░╚═╝░░╚══╝░╚════╝░╚═╝░░╚═╝╚══════╝╚═╝░░╚═╝")
        print(Style.RESET_ALL)
        print("                От создателей EscapeWorld〡Выбран сервер: SCreate")
        print("Введите ник:")
        username = input(">")
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        print("")
        print(Fore.WHITE + "      ███████╗██╗░░░░░░█████╗░██╗░░░██╗███╗░░██╗░█████╗░██╗░░██╗███████╗██████╗░")
        print(Fore.WHITE + "      ██╔════╝██║░░░░░██╔══██╗██║░░░██║████╗░██║██╔══██╗██║░░██║██╔════╝██╔══██╗")
        print(Fore.BLUE + "      █████╗░░██║░░░░░███████║██║░░░██║██╔██╗██║██║░░╚═╝███████║█████╗░░██████╔╝")
        print(Fore.BLUE + "      ██╔══╝░░██║░░░░░██╔══██║██║░░░██║██║╚████║██║░░██╗██╔══██║██╔══╝░░██╔══██╗")
        print(Fore.RED + "      ███████╗███████╗██║░░██║╚██████╔╝██║░╚███║╚█████╔╝██║░░██║███████╗██║░░██║")
        print(Fore.RED + "      ╚══════╝╚══════╝╚═╝░░╚═╝░╚═════╝░╚═╝░░╚══╝░╚════╝░╚═╝░░╚═╝╚══════╝╚═╝░░╚═╝")
        print(Style.RESET_ALL)
        print("                От создателей EscapeWorld〡Выбран сервер: SCreate")
        print("Ник: ", username, "зарегистрирован. Выполняется вход...")
        time.sleep(2.5)
        #print("Проверяю...")
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        print("")
        print(Fore.WHITE + "      ███████╗██╗░░░░░░█████╗░██╗░░░██╗███╗░░██╗░█████╗░██╗░░██╗███████╗██████╗░")
        print(Fore.WHITE + "      ██╔════╝██║░░░░░██╔══██╗██║░░░██║████╗░██║██╔══██╗██║░░██║██╔════╝██╔══██╗")
        print(Fore.BLUE + "      █████╗░░██║░░░░░███████║██║░░░██║██╔██╗██║██║░░╚═╝███████║█████╗░░██████╔╝")
        print(Fore.BLUE + "      ██╔══╝░░██║░░░░░██╔══██║██║░░░██║██║╚████║██║░░██╗██╔══██║██╔══╝░░██╔══██╗")
        print(Fore.RED + "      ███████╗███████╗██║░░██║╚██████╔╝██║░╚███║╚█████╔╝██║░░██║███████╗██║░░██║")
        print(Fore.RED + "      ╚══════╝╚══════╝╚═╝░░╚═╝░╚═════╝░╚═╝░░╚══╝░╚════╝░╚═╝░░╚═╝╚══════╝╚═╝░░╚═╝")
        print(Style.RESET_ALL)
        print("                От создателей EscapeWorld〡Выбран сервер: SCreate")
        print("Проверяем обновление...")
        time.sleep(2.5)
        print("Проверяем файлы...")
        time.sleep(2.5)
        subprocess.run(f"start.bat", username, r"C:/ELauncher")
        time.sleep(2.5)
        break
        #time.sleep(2.5)
    elif key == "2":
        option = "Выбор версии"
        print("Пункт «Выбор версии» в разработке :[")
    elif key == "3":
        option = "Настройка лаунчера"
        print("Пункт «Настройка лаунчера» в разработке :[")
    elif key == "q":
        break
        print(option)

# Запись настроек в JSON файл
def save_settings(nickname, settings):
    with open('C:/ELauncher/settings.json', 'w') as file:
        json.dump({nickname: settings}, file)

# Чтение настроек из JSON файла
def load_settings():
    try:
        with open('C:/ELauncher/settings.json', 'r') as file:
            settings = json.load(file)
            return settings
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return {}

# Сохранение настроек в файл
save_settings(username)

# Загрузка настроек из файла и вывод на экран
value_settings = load_settings()
print(f"Ник: {value_settings.get(username, 'не зарегистрирован!')}")
```

(Пытался что то понять - не получилось:{ )

Батник:

```
echo off
cls
title МОЖЕТЕ ЗАКРЫТЬ ДАННОЕ ОКНО ЕСЛИ ОНО ВАМ МЕШАЕТ! РАЗРАБОТЧИК КРИВОРУКИЙ НЕ УМЕЕТ ДЕЛАТЬ ЛАУНЧЕРА ДЛЯ MINECRAFT 1.18.2!
echo                                      МОЖЕТЕ ЗАКРЫТЬ ДАННОЕ ОКНО!!!
echo ░██████╗████████╗░█████╗░██████╗░████████╗  ███╗░░░███╗██╗███╗░░██╗███████╗░█████╗░██████╗░░█████╗░███████╗████████╗
echo ██╔════╝╚══██╔══╝██╔══██╗██╔══██╗╚══██╔══╝  ████╗░████║██║████╗░██║██╔════╝██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██╔════╝╚══██╔══╝
echo ╚█████╗░░░░██║░░░███████║██████╔╝░░░██║░░░  ██╔████╔██║██║██╔██╗██║█████╗░░██║░░╚═╝██████╔╝███████║█████╗░░░░░██║░░░
echo ░╚═══██╗░░░██║░░░██╔══██║██╔══██╗░░░██║░░░  ██║╚██╔╝██║██║██║╚████║██╔══╝░░██║░░██╗██╔══██╗██╔══██║██╔══╝░░░░░██║░░░
echo ██████╔╝░░░██║░░░██║░░██║██║░░██║░░░██║░░░  ██║░╚═╝░██║██║██║░╚███║███████╗╚█████╔╝██║░░██║██║░░██║██║░░░░░░░░██║░░░
echo ╚═════╝░░░░╚═╝░░░╚═╝░░╚═╝╚═╝░░╚═╝░░░╚═╝░░░  ╚═╝░░░░░╚═╝╚═╝╚═╝░░╚══╝╚══════╝░╚════╝░╚═╝░░╚═╝╚═╝░░╚═╝╚═╝░░░░░░░░╚═╝░░░
C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\jre\java-runtime-beta\windows-x64\java-runtime-beta\bin\javaw.exe -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -Xms512M -Xmx2816M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump "-Djava.library.path=C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\versions\ForgeOptiFine 1.18.2\natives" -Dminecraft.launcher.brand=java-minecraft-launcher -Dminecraft.launcher.version=1.6.84-j -cp "C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\pw\modder\transformerDiscoverer\2.2\transformerDiscoverer-2.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\cpw\mods\securejarhandler\1.0.8\securejarhandler-1.0.8.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\ow2\asm\asm\9.5\asm-9.5.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\ow2\asm\asm-commons\9.5\asm-commons-9.5.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\ow2\asm\asm-tree\9.5\asm-tree-9.5.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\ow2\asm\asm-util\9.5\asm-util-9.5.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\ow2\asm\asm-analysis\9.5\asm-analysis-9.5.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\net\minecraftforge\accesstransformers\8.0.4\accesstransformers-8.0.4.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\antlr\antlr4-runtime\4.9.1\antlr4-runtime-4.9.1.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\net\minecraftforge\eventbus\5.0.3\eventbus-5.0.3.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\net\minecraftforge\forgespi\4.0.15-4.x\forgespi-4.0.15-4.x.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\net\minecraftforge\coremods\5.0.1\coremods-5.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\cpw\mods\modlauncher\9.1.3\modlauncher-9.1.3.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\net\minecraftforge\unsafe\0.2.0\unsafe-0.2.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\com\electronwill\night-config\core\3.6.4\core-3.6.4.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\com\electronwill\night-config\toml\3.6.4\toml-3.6.4.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\apache\maven\maven-artifact\3.6.3\maven-artifact-3.6.3.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\net\jodah\typetools\0.8.3\typetools-0.8.3.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\net\minecrell\terminalconsoleappender\1.2.0\terminalconsoleappender-1.2.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\jline\jline-reader\3.12.1\jline-reader-3.12.1.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\jline\jline-terminal\3.12.1\jline-terminal-3.12.1.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\spongepowered\mixin\0.8.5\mixin-0.8.5.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\openjdk\nashorn\nashorn-core\15.3\nashorn-core-15.3.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\net\minecraftforge\JarJarSelector\0.3.19\JarJarSelector-0.3.19.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\net\minecraftforge\JarJarMetadata\0.3.19\JarJarMetadata-0.3.19.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\cpw\mods\bootstraplauncher\1.0.0\bootstraplauncher-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\net\minecraftforge\JarJarFileSystems\0.3.19\JarJarFileSystems-0.3.19.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\net\minecraftforge\fmlloader\1.18.2-40.2.17\fmlloader-1.18.2-40.2.17.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\com\mojang\logging\1.0.0\logging-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\com\mojang\blocklist\1.0.10\blocklist-1.0.10.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\ru\tln4\empty\0.1\empty-0.1.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\com\github\oshi\oshi-core\5.8.5\oshi-core-5.8.5.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\net\java\dev\jna\jna\5.10.0\jna-5.10.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\net\java\dev\jna\jna-platform\5.10.0\jna-platform-5.10.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.8.0-beta4\slf4j-api-1.8.0-beta4.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-slf4j18-impl\2.17.0\log4j-slf4j18-impl-2.17.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\com\ibm\icu\icu4j\70.1\icu4j-70.1.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\com\mojang\javabridge\1.2.24\javabridge-1.2.24.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\net\sf\jopt-simple\jopt-simple\5.0.4\jopt-simple-5.0.4.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\io\netty\netty-all\4.1.68.Final\netty-all-4.1.68.Final.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\com\google\guava\failureaccess\1.0.1\failureaccess-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\com\google\guava\guava\31.0.1-jre\guava-31.0.1-jre.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.12.0\commons-lang3-3.12.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\commons-io\commons-io\2.11.0\commons-io-2.11.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.15\commons-codec-1.15.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\com\mojang\brigadier\1.0.18\brigadier-1.0.18.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\com\mojang\datafixerupper\4.1.27\datafixerupper-4.1.27.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.8.9\gson-2.8.9.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\by\ely\authlib\3.11.49.2\authlib-3.11.49.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.21\commons-compress-1.21.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.5.13\httpclient-4.5.13.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.2\commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.4.14\httpcore-4.4.14.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\it\unimi\dsi\fastutil\8.5.6\fastutil-8.5.6.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.17.0\log4j-api-2.17.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.17.0\log4j-core-2.17.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\3.2.2\lwjgl-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-jemalloc\3.2.2\lwjgl-jemalloc-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-openal\3.2.2\lwjgl-openal-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-opengl\3.2.2\lwjgl-opengl-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-glfw\3.2.2\lwjgl-glfw-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-stb\3.2.2\lwjgl-stb-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-tinyfd\3.2.2\lwjgl-tinyfd-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries\com\mojang\text2speech\1.12.4\text2speech-1.12.4.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\versions\ForgeOptiFine 1.18.2\ForgeOptiFine 1.18.2.jar" -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=system "-DignoreList=bootstraplauncher,securejarhandler,asm-commons,asm-util,asm-analysis,asm-tree,asm,JarJarFileSystems,client-extra,fmlcore,javafmllanguage,lowcodelanguage,mclanguage,forge-,ForgeOptiFine 1.18.2.jar" -DmergeModules=jna-5.10.0.jar,jna-platform-5.10.0.jar,java-objc-bridge-1.0.0.jar -DlibraryDirectory=C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries -p C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries/cpw/mods/bootstraplauncher/1.0.0/bootstraplauncher-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries/cpw/mods/securejarhandler/1.0.8/securejarhandler-1.0.8.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/9.5/asm-commons-9.5.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries/org/ow2/asm/asm-util/9.5/asm-util-9.5.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/9.5/asm-analysis-9.5.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/9.5/asm-tree-9.5.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries/org/ow2/asm/asm/9.5/asm-9.5.jar;C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\libraries/net/minecraftforge/JarJarFileSystems/0.3.19/JarJarFileSystems-0.3.19.jar --add-modules ALL-MODULE-PATH --add-opens java.base/java.util.jar=cpw.mods.securejarhandler --add-opens java.base/java.lang.invoke=cpw.mods.securejarhandler --add-exports java.base/sun.security.util=cpw.mods.securejarhandler --add-exports jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns=java.naming -Dtransformers.list=optifine:OptiFine:1.18.2_HD_U_H9 -Xss2M cpw.mods.bootstraplauncher.BootstrapLauncher --username %1 --version "ForgeOptiFine 1.18.2" --gameDir C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game --assetsDir C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\assets --assetIndex 1.18 --uuid e8717b21d14941f4b2ce6455e5a14a5b --accessToken eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE3MDc0ODUzOTksImNsaWVudF9pZCI6InRsYXVuY2hlciIsInNjb3BlIjoib2J0YWluX293bl9hY2NvdW50X2luZm8gbWluZWNyYWZ0X3NlcnZlcl9zZXNzaW9uIiwic3ViIjoiZWx5fDQ5NDU3OTcifQ.SybKJkqa7Bv2VV9Wv7tUdeJgGE3GTcBD1tle9wo766xxVzAUh7c9Cs2un6k7i1baGUXL1m1XAfgnmrZCkcPIsA --clientId "" --xuid "" --userType mojang --versionType modified --width 925 --height 530 --launchTarget forgeclient --fml.forgeVersion 40.2.17 --fml.mcVersion 1.18.2 --fml.forgeGroup net.minecraftforge --fml.mcpVersion 20220404.173914 --server 65.21.9.198 --port 25988
```

Ошибка в конце:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Fps_M\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\dev.launcher\ELauncher.py", line 81, in <module>
    subprocess.run(f"start.bat", username, r"C:/ELauncher")
  File "C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 548, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Fps_M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 835, in __init__
    raise TypeError("bufsize must be an integer")
TypeError: bufsize must be an integer
```

после текста "Проверяем файлы."

Comment: Мне бы еще понять что писать в setting.json (Либо он вроде нечего не сохраняет и не загружает, либо я слишком тупой в этом деле)

Comment: Вас не смущает что def save_settings(nickname, settings): имеет два параметры, а вы передаете 1?) Просто попробуете понять что делает код из моего примера и вы сразу сможете его адаптировать под себя.

Comment: @Amgarak я оставил ошибку, как она исправляется? Я вроде +/- понял как передать значение

Comment: А что за параметр r"C:/ELauncher"?

Comment: @Amgarak я подумал что это путь, либо у меня просто файлы разбросаные

Comment: subprocess.run([my_path, username])

Comment: @Amgarak все равно какая же ошибка

Comment: Вы очень не внимательно смотрите что я вам пишу в ответах. Вот тот же параметр `%1%` вы написали в батнике как `%1`. Те же параметры запуска, они передаются как список `subprocess.run([my_path, username])` - вы это исправили?

Comment: Ошибка при сохранение в json-файл:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Fps_M\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\dev.launcher\ELauncher.py", line 110, in <module>
    save_settings(username)
  File "c:\Users\Fps_M\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\dev.launcher\ELauncher.py", line 98, in save_settings
    json.dump({username}, file)
TypeError: Object of type set is not JSON serializable

Comment: Файл settings.json:
пустой